# Law of total probability for conditional distributions

Tags: probability

For three random variables $X,Y,Z$, is it true that

$$ p(Z \vert Y) = \sum_X p(X) p(Z \vert X, Y) $$

I believe this is untrue because you have to condition on the same events to meaningfully perform operations between distributions, but the following should hold?

$$ p(Z \vert Y) = \sum_X p(X \vert Y) p(Z \vert X, Y) $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is not correct in general, but the second one is. For the first one to be correct, you should have independence between $X$ and $Y$.